# Regular Expression Formula Parsing in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to parse this java script formula

**Original Formula:**

```
sum((a+b)*c)+count((a*c)+b)+avg((a-c)/b)+sum((a-c+d)/b)
```

**expected result:**

```
a = (a+b)*c
b = (a*c)+b
c = (a-c)/b
d = (a-c+d)/b
```

What ever we tried is in the link below, please check the link.

https://regex101.com/r/upnlkA/2/

Any Help will be Appreciated, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can the parentheses be nested only one level deep like in the example, or arbitrarily deep?

Comment: Regex is generally not suitable for parsing a nested arithmetic formula.  On top of this, I don't understand whence the LHS in your expected output are coming.

Comment: Please check out this related question matching balanced parentheses. It seems to work for what you need:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses#answer-19863847

Comment: The LHS Doest matter for the purpose of understanding i just added that the result i expect is the same "(a+b)*c" please ignore the LHS part and Thanks for your response @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 1):

First off, if the structure of the formula is expected to change then you should *not* use a regex. If this is the case you should use a package like [extract-brackets](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extract-brackets/v/0.0.4).

If the formula is not going to change its structure considerably then you can use this regex:

`/\w{2,}\((.+?)\)(?=(\+\w{2,}|$))/gm`

https://regex101.com/r/wBrheL/1/

It will give you the following groups:

- (a+b)*c
- (a*c)+b
- (a-c)/b
- (a-c+d)/b

You can find the detailed explanation in the link. The human-readable explanation is that it looks for words with 2 or more characters `\w{2,}`, begins extracting and stops until it finds another word with 2 or more characters or the end of the string `$`